# Get dates from the current calendar month and the next 11 coming months

Tags: c#, linq

I have an `IEnumerable<DateTime>`.  I would like to pull out all dates that occur in the current calendar month even if they have passed as well as all dates in the next 11 calendar months.  I'll be displaying the dates grouped by month starting with the most recent.  For example:

Current Date - Mar 12 2012

- March 2012

  - March 3  - Event 1
  - March 15 - Event 2
  - March 30 - Event 3
- ...
- ...
- ...
- February 2013

  - Feb 3 - Event 156
  - Feb 13 - Event 157
  - Feb 20 - Event 158

I already know how to do the grouping part.  How would you accomplish filtering the dates using linq and C#?

Comment: Did you have a question?

Comment: What if you show what your IEnumerable contains?

Comment: What are you having trouble with exactly? The grouping or the condition to include an event or not?

Comment: I just need help with the condition to include or exclude a date.  I only mentioned the grouping to give context to what I'm using the code for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work. You first determine the legal range of dates, then filter out any dates that are outside of that range, and finally you group them by month.

I wrote the following code by hand, you may need to tweak it:

```
var acceptableFirstDate = DateTime.Today;
if (DateTime.Today.Day > 1)
{
    acceptableFirstDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-DateTime.Today.Day + 1);
}
var acceptableLastDate = acceptableFirstDate.AddMonths(12).AddDays(-1);

var result = dates
    .Where(x => x >= acceptableFirstDate && x <= acceptableLastDate)
    .GroupBy(x => x.Month);
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: This worked fine except for one thing.  I need to make line number 6 be "var acceptableLastDate = acceptableFirstDate.AddMonths(12).AddDays(-1)".  In my example I would want Feb 28 2013 as my last day and not Mar 1 2013.  Thanks a lot for the help though!